# Merging two dataframes on a date range in R

Tags: r, datetime, merge, sqldf

In R I want to merge two dataframes on a range of dates, taking all rows from the second dataframe which fall on and between two columns of dates from the first dataframe. I couldn't find a strictly R function or version of the merge function that could do this, but I know there's a 'between' function in sql and I was thinking of trying the sqldf package (although I'm not well versed in sql). If there's a more R-ish way to do this, that would be preferable. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:2, PtID = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = c("T031", "T040", "T045", "T064", "T074", "T081", "T092", "T094", "T096", "T105", "T107", "T108", "T115", "T118", "T120", "T124", "T125", "T128", "T130", "T132", "T138", "T140", "T142", "T142_R1", "T146", "T158", "T159", "T160", "T164", "T166", "T169", "T171", "T173", "T197", "T208", "T214", "T221"), class = "factor"), StartDateTime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0), min = c(11L, 35L), hour = c(17L, 17L), mday = c(23L, 23L), mon = c(9L, 9L), year = c(112L, 112L), wday = c(2L, 2L), yday = c(296L, 296L), isdst = c(1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), EndDateTime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0), min = c(16L, 37L), hour = c(17L, 17L), mday = c(23L, 23L), mon = c(9L, 9L), year = c(112L, 112L), wday = c(2L, 2L), yday = c(296L, 296L), isdst = c(1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("ID", "PtID", "StartDateTime", "EndDateTime"), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

df1

```
  ID PtID       StartDateTime         EndDateTime
1  1 T031 2012-10-23 17:11:00 2012-10-23 17:16:00
2  2 T031 2012-10-23 17:35:00 2012-10-23 17:37:00
```

The second dataframe has several IDs (which match the first dataframe) and timestamps on the minute level.

df2

```
df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), dateTime = structure(list(sec = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), min = 2:44, hour = c(17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), mday = c(23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L), mon = c(9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), year = c(112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L), wday = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), yday = c(296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L, 296L), isdst = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("sec", "min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt")), lat = c(33.06621406, 33.06616621, 33.06617305, 33.06617624, 33.06617932, 33.06618161, 33.06618326, 33.06618604, 33.06615089, 33.06628004, 33.06618461, 33.06615113, 33.0661362, 33.06620301, 33.0662218, 33.06624283, 33.06622268, 33.06622425, 33.06622787, 33.06623042, 33.06623318, 33.06623654, 33.06623826, 33.06623919, 33.06623907, 33.06624009, 33.06623804, 33.06624255, 33.06624377, 33.06624446, 33.06624242, 33.06624254, 33.06624513, 33.06624582, 33.06615573, 33.06625534, 33.06618541, 33.06613825, 33.06613624, 33.06614027, 33.06614551, 33.06614844, 33.06615393), lon = c(-116.6105531, -116.6105651,-116.6105613, -116.6105553, -116.610551, -116.610549, -116.6105484, -116.6105512, -116.6105712, -116.6104996, -116.6104711, -116.6104854, -116.6105596, -116.6104509, -116.610524, -116.6105535, -116.6105461, -116.6105461, -116.6105477, -116.6105498, -116.6105478, -116.6105473, -116.6105473, -116.6105488, -116.6105497, -116.6105479, -116.610545, -116.6105461, -116.6105448, -116.610543, -116.6105409, -116.6105395, -116.6105367, -116.6105337, -116.6105344, -116.6104779, -116.6104953,-116.6105222, -116.610526, -116.6105255, -116.6105282, -116.6105265,-116.6105282)), .Names = c("ID", "dateTime", "lat", "lon"), row.names = 1023:1065, class = "data.frame")
```

So the desired output would look like this:

```
ID PtID       DateTime         lat     lon
1 T031    2012-10-23 17:11:00    33.06628 -116.6105
1 T031    2012-10-23 17:12:00    33.06618 -116.6105
1 T031    2012-10-23 17:13:00    33.06615 -116.6105
1 T031    2012-10-23 17:14:00    33.06614 -116.6106
1 T031    2012-10-23 17:15:00    33.06620 -116.6105
1 T031    2012-10-23 17:16:00    33.06622 -116.6105
2 T031    2012-10-23 17:35:00    33.06625 -116.6105
2 T031    2012-10-23 17:36:00    33.06616 -116.6105
2 T031    2012-10-23 17:37:00    33.06626 -116.6105
```

So with sqldf maybe something like this?

```
sqldf("SELECT df2.ID, df2.lon, df2.lat, FROM df1
INNER JOIN df2 ON df1.ID = df2.ID
WHERE df2.DateTime BETWEEN df1.StartDateTime AND df1.EndDateTime")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, its not a good idea to use POSIXlt in data frames.  Use POSIXct instead.  Also your SQL statement is ok except the comma before FROM needs to be removed:

```
df1a <- transform(df1, 
           StartDateTime = as.POSIXct(StartDateTime),
           EndDateTime = as.POSIXct(EndDateTime))
df2a <- transform(df2, dateTime = as.POSIXct(dateTime))
```

The SQL statement in the question has an extraneous commma before `FROM`.

Here is a slightly simplified statement.  This one uses a left join instead to ensure that all ID's from `df1a` are included even if they have no matches in `df2a`.

```
sqldf("SELECT df1a.ID, PtID, dateTime, lat, lon 
  FROM df1a LEFT JOIN df2a 
  ON df1a.ID = df2a.ID AND dateTime BETWEEN StartDateTime AND EndDateTime")
```

Comment: Thanks! I always miss the small things. However, the new sql statement just matches up the ID 1's and not all the ID's present. Is there a way to make sure it matches up all ID's with their perspective date ranges?

Comment: I have modified it using a left join in order to output every ID in df1a even if there are no matches in df2a.  (Note that your sample output does not correspond to the sample inputs.)

Comment: Right, the IDs should have been 2 instead of 3 in the second df. Sorry  about that. This is perfect though, thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a way to do this with dplyr or other packages?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into defining your data as `zoo` objects. `merge.zoo` does something very close to what you ask. Refer to this question for more: [R: merge two irregular time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7089444/r-merge-two-irregular-time-series-solved)